# Android webview href not support in html page

Tags: javascript, android

I want to load to a about.html page inside asset folder by clicking a button in index.html inside android webview.

Here's the code:

Button:

```
<a href="about.html">About</a>
```

Java:

```
    WebView browser = (WebView) findViewById(webview);
    browser.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return false;
        }
    });
```

But the problem is when i click on button it doesn't load about.html but if I add a javascript function with below code it works.. but i want to use href.

Code:

```
<button onclick="about()">About</button>
 <script>
        function about() {
            location.href = "about.html";
        }   
</script>
```

How do I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

write an interface for TagHandler and in your fromHtml method check for the tag and handle it by loading the page

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html

Answer (score 0):

try this code:

```
private void loadWebView(WebView webView,String htmlString)
{
 try {
         final String mimeType = "text/html";
         final String encoding = "UTF-8";

            WebViewClient yourWebClient = new WebViewClient()
            {
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView  view, String  url)
                {
                 // This line we let me load only pages inside  Webpage
                 if ( url.contains("") == true )
                    // Load new URL Don't override URL Link
                    return false;

                 // Return true to override url loading (In this case do nothing).
                 return true;
                }
            };


            // Get Web view
            webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);   
            webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true); 
            webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
            webView.setWebViewClient(yourWebClient);

            // Load URL
            webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", htmlString, mimeType, encoding, "");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

use it as:

```
loadWebView(browser, "file:///android_asset/www/index.html")  //pass url
```